# Symfony - Could not determine access type for property "id"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity

I get this error:

> Could not determine access type for property "id"

Then I read on the internet that I need to add a set function for id. But that only led to other errors.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Product
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="product")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ProductRepository")
 */
class Product
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Categorie", inversedBy=”producten”)
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="categorie", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $categorie;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="naam", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $naam;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="merk", type="string", length=100, nullable=true)
     */
    private $merk;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="inkoopprijs", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2, nullable=true)
     */
    private $inkoopprijs;


    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set categorie
     *
     * @param integer $categorie
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setCategorie($categorie)
    {
        $this->categorie = $categorie;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get categorie
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getCategorie()
    {
        return $this->categorie;
    }

    /**
     * Set naam
     *
     * @param string $naam
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setNaam($naam)
    {
        $this->naam = $naam;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get naam
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getNaam()
    {
        return $this->naam;
    }

    /**
     * Set merk
     *
     * @param string $merk
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setMerk($merk)
    {
        $this->merk = $merk;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get merk
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMerk()
    {
        return $this->merk;
    }

    /**
     * Set inkoopprijs
     *
     * @param string $inkoopprijs
     *
     * @return Product
     */
    public function setInkoopprijs($inkoopprijs)
    {
        $this->inkoopprijs = $inkoopprijs;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get inkoopprijs
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getInkoopprijs()
    {
        return $this->inkoopprijs;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code that is causing your error.

Comment: You shoul add the full stacktrace of the error and where/when it appear. Also read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you try using the `app_dev.php` URL as [described here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/environments.html#executing-an-application-in-different-environments) to see if you can get the stacktrace like @gp_sflover has asked? It might help you see where the problem is.

Comment: @gp_sflover trace is incredibly meaningless. 
Something like:       "/var/www/cheapmarina/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/Form.php:498",
"/var/www/cheapmarina/vendor/sonata-project/admin-bundle/src/Controller/CRUDController.php:336",
before is HttpKernel.php and after is PropertyAccessor

Comment: @gp_sflover there is nothing about AppBundle or any other user code =\

Answer (score 1):

Remove `name="id"`, or try this construction for you `id` field.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. But it was this: inversedBy=”producten” . I have copy/paste it but it must be inversedBy="producten"

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
/**
 * Fake
 *
 * @see fabien good guy
 */
public function setId($id) {}
```